# Saving PDF in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ipad, pdf

I open up a graphics context and do some drawing using quartz core functions in my pdf and then try to save by opening up a pdf context with the below function:

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(updatedFilePath, pdfSize, nil);
```

Then I draw page by page using the below function:

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfSize, nil);
```

The problem is I need to save every page even if I draw in only one pdf page. Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: So you want to draw the entire pdf with one call instead of multiple calls to `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo`?

Comment: I am not concerned with the function to be used. Just need to make my saving process more efficient unlike now. Same function or even any other method would do if it is better than the existing one. Thanks.

Comment: so your current method of drawing the pdf has performance issues?

Comment: yes, you are right. I want it to be made better.

Answer (score 0):

In iphone, there is no such method that you can create only one page and replace that in existing PDF, not there is a way to copy PDF, you need to create it entirely.